# High Memory Footprint in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, memory, azure-functions

I'm using some simple C# code on .NET Core to look at how Azure Functions perform.

The use case is this: add 10 million int values to an ArrayList as part of an Azure Function, and use a time trigger set to 1 minute to invoke the function. (I know the ArrayList is obsolete and not to be used anymore, but I'm just employing it to get a significant chunk of space allocated on the heap).
Therefore the function's C# code is this:

```
using System.Collections;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
    Random random = new Random(1);
    int noNumbers = 10000000;
    for(int i=0;i<noNumbers;i++) {
        numbers.Add(random.Next(10));
    }

    log.LogInformation($"Created an ArrayList of {numbers.Count} elements");
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

I've checked the platform settings and seen this is 32-bit (I'm *assuming* that this refers to the .NET Core runtime being 32-bit):

[image]

Running the same sample code in a "desktop" environment, targeting .NET Core 3.0 on Windows 10 x64, and using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize` to get the overall allocated memory yields the following results (VMMap output, followed by console output):
[image]
[image]

The values match what's expected, as follows:

- Assuming the GC recclaims the unused data before the code completes the final memory allocations, only the final state will matter. The ArrayList is implemented by allocating object[] arrays whose length double as the number of elements outgrow the current one; for the last such internal array, its length will be 16,777,216 and each object reference is 4 bytes (32-bit platform), thus consuming 67,108,864 bytes (exactly 64 MB); the boxed ints themselves will take 10 mil x 12 bytes = 120,000,000 bytes (~117 MB), yielding a total of ~181 MB, quite similar to what VMMap shows in the "Private" column
- For an ArrayList, each boxed int occupies 12 bytes, due to the type object pointer (aka method table address – 4 bytes), the value stored (an int, which takes 4 bytes on either x86/x64) and the sync block index (4 bytes). All these scattered boxed ints total 114.45 MB (12 bytes/object x 10 mil objects). On top of this we have the internal arrays themselves that get allocated in turn, and which take 128 MB (16 bytes + 32 bytes + 64 bytes + … + 32 MB + 64 MB). The total comes up to 242.45 MB, which is close to what the console output prints

The observed outcome for the Azure Function however is as follows (metrics graph, followed by a manual run of the function itself):
[image]

[image]

The private bytes measured on the graph is way above what was seen previously in VMMap, while the number of bytes allocated over the lifetime of the function neither matches the expected memory usage for neither x86 code(~240MB), nor x64 (~500MB). This would suggest x86 code running, but with something extra on top (whose overhead is not negligible), which impacts the private bytes significantly. However, the value observed does come close to the "private bytes" metric measured in the Azure portal for the Azure Function (both Function App’s “private bytes” or the App Insights’ “process private bytes” are about the same).

**What would be the explanation for the number of private bytes being double in Azure Functions as opposed to running the same code on a regular machine ?**

Why would this matter anyway ? For 2 reasons:

1. [Charging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) is performed per memory consumption (as one of the criteria), as the number of private bytes is referenced as the metric used to compute this ([link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1339#issuecomment-539771855))
2. There's currently a limit of 1.5 GB of memory used by an Azure function; as long as memory usage is higher than one would expect, the actual maximum limit for the types allocated would be lower in consequence (eg I'd have to aim to use just 1.0 GB worth of memory structures, since the rest up to 1.5 GB is inexplicably used by the runtime within Azure Functions)

A corresponding GitHub issue has already been opened [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5654).